# SetWindowLongW & Error 1413

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I'm trying to set the owner (not parent) of a Win32 windows via python and ctypes.

When I call:

```
GWL_HWNDPARENT = -8
ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongW(hWndChild, GWL_HWNDPARENT, hWndParent)
```

it fails and `ctypes.GetLastError()` returns 1413 - ERROR_INVALID_INDEX ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Both the hWndChild and hWndParent seem valid because I can use `ctypes.windll.user32.SetParent` successfully.

I'm confused. What does the Invalid Index refer to?

---

Updated according to comments.

This requires two instances of notepad editing `OwnerWindow.txt` and `NonOwnerWindow.txt` respectively

```
import ctypes

GWL_HWNDPARENT      = -8 

_FindWindow          = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW
_FindWindow.argtypes = [ctypes.c_wchar_p,ctypes.c_wchar_p]
_FindWindow.restype  = ctypes.c_void_p

_SetWindowLong          = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongW
_SetWindowLong.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_long]
_SetWindowLong.restype  = ctypes.c_void_p

oHWnd = _FindWindow('Notepad', 'OwnerWindow.txt - Notepad')
nHWnd = _FindWindow('Notepad', 'NonOwnerWindow.txt - Notepad')

print "Last Error: {0}".format(str(ctypes.GetLastError()))
_SetWindowLong(ctypes.c_int(nHWnd), ctypes.c_int(GWL_HWNDPARENT), ctypes.c_int(oHWnd))
print "Last Error: {0}".format(str(ctypes.GetLastError()))
```

Comment: Is it a 64-bit process, which requires using `SetWindowLongPtrW`? Or is `hWndChild` actually a child window, which can have a parent but not an owner? You can check if either is a child window: `ischild = lambda hwnd: bool(GetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_CHILD)`, where `GWL_STYLE == -16` and `WS_CHILD == 0x40000000`.

Comment: In deference to the child-state of the potential owner, see [Raymond Chen's PDC'05 Slide Deck](http://www.slideshare.net/wvdang/five-things-every-win32-developer-should-know); fast-forward to slide 29 for the bits of interest. @eryksun is correct that I should have asked the platform and child-state, which I assumed was child for both (not good).

Comment: Please edit your question, telling us if your two windows are child window(s) or Top Level window(s)

Comment: @manuell Both windows were top level widow; I still got the 1413 error if I used two individual instances of notepad.

Comment: @E.Beach If I try with two Top-Level HWNDs, I get 87 (Invalid Parameter). In order to get 1413, I have to pass funky index, as 3548 (raw WinAPI with C++ here)

Comment: @eryksun In the end, the 1413 result because I was executing SetWindowLongW on win64.  With the example below, this question is solved for me but I've updated it with a more completed example generating the 1413.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I made some test and (re)read documentation, taking into account comments from @eryksun.

The only way to know if the [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) failed or succeeded is to use `SetLastError(0)` just before the call, and then to use `GetLastError` after the call, if the call returned 0.

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the previous value of
>   the specified 32-bit integer.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error
>   information, call GetLastError.
>
> If the previous value of the specified 32-bit integer is zero, and the
>   function succeeds, the return value is zero, but the function does not
>   clear the last error information. This makes it difficult to determine
>   success or failure. To deal with this, you should clear the last error
>   information by calling SetLastError with 0 before calling
>   SetWindowLong. Then, function failure will be indicated by a return
>   value of zero and a GetLastError result that is nonzero.

If the C/C++ code from `ctypes` does *insert* Win32 APIs call beetween your `SetLastError` call and the final `SetWindowLong` call, you can't know if there is success or failure.

**ctypes `use_last_error` example:**

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *
from ctypes import _SimpleCData

user32le = WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
user32le.SetWindowLongW.restype = LONG
user32le.SetWindowLongW.argtypes = [HWND, c_int, LONG]
LONG_PTR = HWND  # should be an integer, but a pointer is simpler
if sizeof(HWND) == sizeof(c_long):  # WIN32
    # WIN32: this is a macro in winuser.h
    user32le.SetWindowLongPtrW = user32le.SetWindowLongW
elif sizeof(HWND) == sizeof(c_longlong):  # WIN64
    user32le.SetWindowLongPtrW.restype = LONG_PTR
    user32le.SetWindowLongPtrW.argtypes = [HWND, c_int, LONG_PTR]

def SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong):
    if isinstance(dwNewLong, _SimpleCData):
        # avoid ArgumentError with LONG, etc
        dwNewLong = dwNewLong.value
    # set last_error to 0, and save the previous value
    last_error = set_last_error(0)
    try:
        # ctypes calls GetLastError / SetLastError to swap 
        # LastError and last_error
        result = user32le.SetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong)
        # ctypes again swaps LastError and last_error
    finally:
        last_error = set_last_error(last_error)          
    if not result and last_error:
        raise WinError(last_error)
    return result
```

Comment: Use `SetParent` if that's what you need, but there's no `SetOwner` function in user32. If the parent is the desktop (i.e. a top-level window), then getting and setting `GWL_HWNDPARENT` actually applies to the owner field in the window data structure instead of the parent field.

Comment: ReactOS is the closest I can get to a "source" link. `SetWindowLongW` calls `NtUserSetWindowLong`, which in ReactOS calls [`co_UserSetWindowLong`](http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/tags/ReactOS-0.3.16/reactos/win32ss/user/ntuser/window.c?view=markup#l3602). On line 3710 it calls `IntSetOwner` if the parent is the desktop. Similarly, `GetWindowLongW` calls [`IntGetWindowLong`](http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/tags/ReactOS-0.3.16/reactos/win32ss/user/user32/windows/class.c?view=markup#l1100), which returns the owner if the parent is the desktop.

Comment: @eryksun Yes. The link from The Old New Thing is pretty clear. Child Windows have a parent but NO owner. "Not child" Windows have NO parent, but *may* have an owner. Using `SetParent` set the parent of a child window, and may be used to set the owner of a "non child" window.

Comment: @eryksun Not enough fluent in python/ctypes to edit the answer with your last comment. Feel free to do it, if you want.

Comment: It doesn't explain the 1413 error, but it does demonstrate how to use SetWindowLong/SetWindowLongPtr.  Thanks!